сохранение значения после перезагрузки страницы
могу не правильно обьяснить но мне надо чтобы сохранялось число после того как оно прибавилось, у меня получалось но сохранялось число до которого оно максимум может дойти путем прибавления, не знаю как это сделать максимальное число - 5.664000 id - trxAmount
index.html


<div class="wrapper2">
  <div class="row mt-0 text-center">
    <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-1"></div>
    <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-10">
      <center>
        <div class="mining">
          <div class="rot"></div>
          <div class="rot2 animated pulse infinite slow"></div>
        </div>
      </center>
      <h2 class="logo-title text-uppercase pb-2 pt-2">
        <b id="trxAmount">5.664000</b>
        <span class="notranslate"><b>₽</b></span>
      </h2>
      <form action="" method="POST">
        <div class="mb-3 login-home"></div>
      </form>
      <script>
        (function() {
          var writeTo = document.getElementById("trxAmount");
          var targetValue = 5.664000; // Set your target value
          var sec = 0.000000;
          var a = setInterval(function() {
            sec = sec + (0.010000 / 1000);
            writeTo.innerHTML = sec.toFixed(6);
            if (sec >= targetValue) {
              clearInterval(a); // Stop the interval when the target is reached
            }
          }, 100);
        })();
      </script>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




Ничего не понял, но очень интересно. Сохраняйте значение в Local Storage и считывайте его при перезагрузке - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Самый просто способ - использования localStorage для таких целей. Как работать? Всё просто! Сохраняем значение:
localStorage.setItem('target', targetValue)

Получаем значение:
let targetValue = localStorage.getItem('target')



мне надо чтобы сохранялось число после того как оно прибавилось, у меня получалось

т.е. проблема не с сохранением

но сохранялось число до которого оно максимум может дойти путем прибавления
не знаю как это сделать максимальное число - 5.664000

а с тем, что сохраняем. проверим что на практике


<div class="wrapper2">
  <div class="row mt-0 text-center">
    <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-1"></div>
    <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-10">
      <center>
        <div class="mining">
          <div class="rot"></div>
          <div class="rot2 animated pulse infinite slow"></div>
        </div>
      </center>
      <h2 class="logo-title text-uppercase pb-2 pt-2">
        <b id="trxAmount">5.664000</b>
        <span class="notranslate"><b>₽</b></span>
      </h2>
      <form action="" method="POST">
        <div class="mb-3 login-home"></div>
      </form>
      <script>
        (function() {
          var writeTo = document.getElementById("trxAmount");
          var targetValue = 5.664000; // Set your target value
          var sec = 5.663800; /*!!!!!!! чтоб не ждать "пол года"*/
          var a = setInterval(function() {
            sec = sec + (0.010000 / 1000);
            writeTo.innerHTML = sec.toFixed(6);
            if (sec >= targetValue) {
              clearInterval(a); // Stop the interval when the target is reached
            }
          }, 100);
        })();
      </script>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



и да, на выходе получаем 5,664010 вместо 5,664000


<div class="wrapper2">
  <div class="row mt-0 text-center">
    <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-1"></div>
    <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-10">
      <center>
        <div class="mining">
          <div class="rot"></div>
          <div class="rot2 animated pulse infinite slow"></div>
        </div>
      </center>
      <h2 class="logo-title text-uppercase pb-2 pt-2">
        <b id="trxAmount">5.664000</b>
        <span class="notranslate"><b>₽</b></span>
      </h2>
      <form action="" method="POST">
        <div class="mb-3 login-home"></div>
      </form>
      <script>
        (function() {
          var writeTo = document.getElementById("trxAmount");
          var targetValue = 5.664000; // Set your target value
          var sec = 5.663800; /*!!!!!!! чтоб не ждать "пол года"*/
          var a = setInterval(function() {
            sec += 0.00001;
            writeTo.innerHTML = sec.toFixed(6);
            if (sec >= (targetValue-0.00001)) { /*!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            вот так с ходу, ничего умнее пока не придумал, но наверняка можно и изящнее. */
              clearInterval(a); // Stop the interval when the target is reached
            }
          }, 100);
        })();
      </script>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



